# What if 2 identical pebbles were carbon dated, 1 exposed to time dilation through an extreme force of gravity, and then both carbon dated again?

Tags: time, time-dilation

Essentially the question asks if time dilation has any effect on carbon dating

Comment: Why wouldn’t it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can radioactivity be slowed through time dilation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/239549/can-radioactivity-be-slowed-through-time-dilation)